# Showing only the selected item with a combo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-widgets

I am trying react-widgets to use a combo box in my nextjs app.

Using one example found in the documentation I get this display:

[image]

But I only want to see the list of choices when I click the arrow of the combo.
Once the choice is done I only want to see my choice and nothing else.

How can I obtain this result ?

In fact the list only shows up after I make my choice and stays there instead of going away.